# Is it possible to raise an event when iPhone shuts down?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to do an app that do something when the user tries to turn off its idevice. Is this possible? Is there an event in iOS SDK for this?

Comment: I wanted to get notified before the app switched off to save the analytics data. I put a breakpoint in `applicationWillTerminate` method in appdelegate  and switched off the device directly. The execution stopped in this method just before the power off. I think we can use `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` to check and so some task just before the app gets killed/powered off.

Answer (score 3):

No, this can't be done. There is no API available to 3rd party apps to be notified when the device is shutting down.

Comment: Thanks, very much... It would be nice to be able to do something like that. :(

Comment: Are you sure about this?